# input type date not supported in some android devices in phonegap application

Tags: android, html, cordova, datepicker

in my phonegap application i have use **html5** **date** type **input**. but it does not show me date picker in some of the android devices.

i have use like this :

```
<input type="date" id="bdate">
```

There is any other alternative to this so it can support in all android device?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi the datepicker not works on most of the Androids [Check this](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html). If you  need date picker please use anything like this http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/demo.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to test your app with an android virtual device you won't get the native datepicker (It happened to me on a 4.3 Android virtual device). Be sure to confirm the functionality on some actual physical devices. I have tested the date input in three devices: the first running Android 4.3, another one with Android 4.1 and another one with Android 2.3. The first two responded as expected showing the native datepicker.